# jQuery Mobile showing spinner after upgrading to 1.3.2

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I just upgraded my C#, ASP.NET MVC app to use jQuery 1.9.1 and jquery Mobile 1.3.2 and now I get a spinner when I load **ANY** pages.  I know what do to do make it go a way

```
    $.mobile.loading('hide'), but
```

however, it did not do this before.  Why is it doing this now and how can I get it to go away without issuing the above command for each page?

Comment: I just found the issue.  I had included the line below twice.  I had been moving script includes around some and I must have forgotten to delete the line after I had moved it. `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had included the line below twice. I must have forgotten to delete the line after I had moved it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```